# Is it possible to remove the triangle from firefox toolbarbutton with type="panel"

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, xul

When developing a firefox extension to show a panel below the icon, the toolbarbutton with type="panel" puts a little triangle inside the button. Is it possible to remove this triangle and keep the type="panel"? Screenshot:

[image: Triangle inside button]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<toolbarbutton type="panel">` is [implemented as an XBL binding](http://hg.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/file/a6104e0e5a2c/toolkit/content/xul.css#l151). If you look at the [source of that XBL binding](http://hg.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/file/a6104e0e5a2c/toolkit/content/widgets/toolbarbutton.xml#l34), there is an anonymous `<dropmarker>` element - this is the dropdown arrow ("triangle") you want to hide. Hiding it is easily possible with CSS:

```css
#my-toolbar-button dropmarker {
  display: none;
}
```

Comment: Thank you Wladimir. It works great. As always very helpful :)